# Convert SHP to MIF/MID

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, mapinfo, mif

I am new to GIS and QGIS software.

is there a batch convert function to convert shape files to mif/mid files?

I can do this individually but is time consuming? 
I have seen similar functions on here to other formats but i cannot convert them for my needs. ie create both mif + mid files.

Is there a plugin?

I use windows 8. My output folder is C:\Data\Submit

I am looking for something simple like this;
[Exporting several files at same time in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131104/export-several-files-at-the-same-time-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single layer, the recipe to export with Python to MIF/MID is the following (deduced from "Dataset Creation Options" of [GDAL MapInfo documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_mitab.html)) :

```
vLayer = iface.activeLayer()
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vLayer, 
        '/tmp/' + vLayer.name() + ".mif", "utf-8", 
        vLayer.crs(), 'Mapinfo File', datasourceOptions='FORMAT=MIF')
```

You can now combine this with step 5 from your link [Export several files at the same time in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131104/export-several-files-at-the-same-time-in-qgis)

Answer (score 3):

You can use ogr2ogr from GDAL Utilities to batch convert several shape files to mid/mif. If you use OSGeo4W installer you can easy install GDAL Utilities. A simple script for you to convert all shape to mif/mid in the current directory:

`@echo off for %%f in (*.shp) do (
    set name=%%~nf
    ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" %name% -dsco FORMAT=MIF %%f 
)`