# Multiple Layers into Indiviual Shapefiles QGIS

Tags: qgis, oracle-dbms, batch

I have extracted about 20 different tables out of an Oracle DB into a project now I want to save each one as a shapefile. 
I know how to save an individual layer into a shapefile but is there a way to save them all at once.

Comment: I found some help using python.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131104/exporting-several-files-at-same-time-in-qgis