# Exporting several layers as GeoPackages at the same time in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, batch, geopackage, vector-layer

I have dozens of temporary Layers. I'd like to export them all as GeoPackages, but I am unsure how to go about doing so without doing each one individually.

I was reviewing this code [Exporting several files at same time in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131104/exporting-several-files-at-same-time-in-qgis/131177#131177?newreg=7fdaa72e41324da59fd412ab2ed7ccf7), but it exports files as *.shp*.

I have tried changing *.shp* to *.gkpg* and ESRI Shapefile to GeoPackage, but the code generated errors.

I did verify, however, that I can get the original code to run:

```py
myDir = 'C:/temp/'

for vLayer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( vLayer, 
        myDir + vLayer.name() + ".shp", "utf-8", 
        vLayer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile" )
```

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to use the ["Package layers"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html#package-layers) tool as a [Batch Process](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/processing/batch_conversion.html).

[image: tool]

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Package layers](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html#package-layers) tool, and you can export the styles and metadata.

The problem in your code is the name of the OGR driver. You must set the OGR driver to `GPKG` instead of `GeoPackage`.

```py
myDir = ''

for vLayer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vLayer, 
        myDir + vLayer.name() + ".gpkg",
        "utf-8", 
        vLayer.crs(),
        "GPKG")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It looks like this may work as a workaround, but I would still prefer to find a solution in PyQGIS form as it will be quicker and easier for naming purposes. Much obliged if you have any suggestions in that form!

Comment: @KateBlackwell, I updated my answer.